# Creating a URI based on form values

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I have a form and I would like to send the details that have been inputted into the form into the uri using post.  I am just not sure how to go about this.

I will have:

Number:
Call:

I would like to generate http://domian.co.nz/page.php?login=xxxx&password=xxxx&number=12345&call678910 etc

I will have the login and pw preset but how would I pass the data from the form into the action?

Here is a concept idea that I have come up with still not 100%:

- Dropdown will not post data into uri
- How would I post the call data?

[Code is here](https://gist.github.com/2908988) as it did not like the stack system

Comment: Your question is still unclear to me. you want to pass login, password and number with POST method, right?

Comment: @3p3r  I have put up an concept idea

Comment: So you want to dynamically change the action according to form parameters?

Comment: @3p3r yes see my example,  I am just about there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your form fields into the URL when you submit you need to use 'GET' as your form `method`, not `POST`.

Although in your example you're passing the password. I don't think that's a good idea to show that in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your URI is only correct for a GET request.

A post request doesn't put the parameters in the URI but in the body of the request.

The server expects the body of your POST request to be in multipart/form-data format  as defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-data-set

The simplest is to use a form and let HTML send elements in multipart.

Usually you'll let the user fill the two fields login and password in order to login :

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="yoururl.php">
    <input type=text name=login>
    <input type=password name=password>
    <input type=submit value="login">
</FORM>
```

The user simply has to click the "login" button to send the request in post.

But if you don't want the fields to appear in your page, you may use hidden inputs :

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="yoururl.php">
    <input type=hidden name=login>
    <input type=hidden name=password>
</FORM>
```

Supposing you're using javascript, you can do this :

```
var form = document.forms[0];
form.login = "mylogin";
form.password = "mypassword";
form.submit();
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I can send data to the action via the form?

Comment: Edited. But please try to find what's your precise problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse POST request and GET request.

Assuming we have:

```
inputOne = valueOne
inputTwo = valueTwo
inputThree = valueThree
```

In GET request all you should do is to pass these on desired URI:

protocol://domain/page`?inputOne=valueOne&inputTwo=valueTwo&inputThree=valueThree`

In GET, all parameters travel through URI better I'd say but in POST, parameters travel through HTTP request. something like this:

```
POST /mysite/page HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:80
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 416
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:80
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/mysite/signup/form.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,hr;q=0.6
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

inputOne:valueOne
inputTwo:valueTwo
inputThree:valueThree
```

Now it depends on your situation:

***If you're on client-side:***

**GET:**

- You may redirect user to appropriate URI with parameters
- You may send an AJAX request with GET method to the desired URI
- You may generate a dynamic form with GET method attribute and submit it via javascript

**POST:**

- You may send an AJAX request with POST method to the desired URI
- You may generate a dynamic form with POST method attribute and submit it via javascript

***If you're on server-side:***

**GET:**

- You may redirect user to appropriate URI with parameters using HTTP headers

**POST:**

- You may build a HTTP request manually
- You may use cURL

*Sidenote:* there are other options but these are the most common ones.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for an email form!

The form:

```
<form method="post" action="my.php">
<input name="vv[Name]" class="textfield" type="text" />
<input name="vv[Email]" class="textfield" type="text" />
<input name="Reset" value="Reset" class="input" type="reset" />
<input name="Submit" value="Submit" class="input" type="submit" />
```

my.php

```
<?
$to = mail@domain.com";
$subject = "Contact form ";
$from = $_POST['vv']['Email'];

$valid=1;
$message ='';
foreach ($_POST['vv'] as $k=>$v){
if (trim($v)=='')$valid=0;
$k = str_replace('_',' ',$k);
$message .="$k : $v<br>";
}
$message .="<hr />IP: {$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}";

function sndmail($from,$to,$subject,$message){
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from ."\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}

if ($valid=='1') {
sndmail($from,$to,$subject,$message);
header( 'Location: correct.html' ) ;
}
else header( 'Location: error.html' ) ;

?>
```

Hope this will help you

[EDIT] Now i read more carefull the question and saw that my answer is not quite right for your problem. Sorry about this!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dystroy's answer, here is a dynamic way to POST data using dynamically created forms via javascript:

***Pure javascript:***

```
var dynForm = document.createElement('form');
dynForm.setAttribute('method','POST');
dynForm.setAttribute('action','');
dynForm.setAttribute('id','dynForm');
dynForm.innerHTML = '';
dynForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="login" value="xxxx" />';
dynForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="password" value="xxxx" />';
dynForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="number" value="12345" />';
dynForm.innerHTML += '<input type="hidden" name="call" value="678910" />';
document.body.appendChild(dynForm);
document.getElementById('dynForm').submit();
```

***jQuery:***

```
$("body").append('<form id="dynForm" action="" method="POST">');
$("#dynForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="login" value="xxxx" />');
$("#dynForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="password" value="xxxx" />');
$("#dynForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="number" value="12345" />');
$("#dynForm").append('<input type="hidden" name="call" value="678910" />');
$("body").append('</form>');
$("#dynForm").submit();
```

---

And this is the technique of POSTing with AJAX:

***Pure javascript:***

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","Desired_URI",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send("login=xxxx&password=xxxx&number=12345&call=678910");
```

***jQuery:***

```
$.post({
  url: 'Desired_URI',
  data: {
    login:'xxxx',
    password:'xxxx',
    number:'12345',
    call:'78910'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go (*based on your Gist*):

```
<?php
    $login = '1236567';
    $password = '10152930';
    $officeNumber = array('0212177899','027899899','09111');
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //I assume that the first entry of $officeNumber is the default number
        //I'm saving base URL for further uses
        var baseActionURI = "https://live.domain.co.nz/call.php?login=<?php echo $login; ?>&password=<?php echo $password; ?>";

        function changeAction()
        {
            var oForm = document.forms[0];
            oForm.setAttribute('action',baseActionURI + "&aparty=" + oForm.elements["officeNumbers"].value + "&bparty=" + oForm.elements["officeNumbers"].value)
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form onsubmit="" method="POST" action="https://live.domain.co.nz/call.php?login=<?php echo $login; ?>&password=<?php echo $password; ?>&aparty=<?php echo $officeNumber[0]; ?>phone&bparty=<?php echo $officeNumber[0];?>">
            <label for="officeNumbers">Office Number:</label>
            <select onchange="javascript:changeAction()" name="officeNumbers" id="officeNumbers">
            <?php
                foreach($officeNumber as $number)
                {
                    echo '<option value="'.$number.'">'.$number.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>';
            ?>
            <label for="callTo">Call:</label>
            <input type="text" name="callTo" id="callTo" />
            <input type="submit" value="Call" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```